# Tower can't connect to git (permission denied) when certificate has different name

Tags: macos, git, ssh-keys, git-tower

I can't connect to to GitHub repo from Tower (Mac OS X), getting permission denied error. I suppose this is caused by different certificate name (github_rsa not id_rsa). I added identity to ssh and from Terminal everything is working correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: You added the certificate that tower uses to github?

Answer (score 2):

If you mention that everything work from the terminal, then you have the correct public/private keys, and you have published your public key on GitHub.

However, Tower won't always use, at first, ssh when connecting to GitHub, which means you also need to enter your GitHub login and token:
See [Tower: Creating a repository on GitHub](http://www.git-tower.com/files/applicationHelp/pgs/ManagingRepositories_CreateGitHub.html), and [GitHub: Set your user name, email and GitHub token](http://help.github.com/set-your-user-name-email-and-github-token/).

The configuration dialog box for Tower creating a repo on GitHub uses those credentials instead of ssh keys:

[image: Tower: creating a new GitHub repo]

After that, is will use an ssh connection for cloning.